# Importing csv file and then sort it with c++

Tags: c++, csv, merge, mergesort

I have a project that told me to import a csv file and then sort it (The file contains million of numbers). I googled for a merge sort source code and found this, i tried it and the sorting is working. (I compiled this code in ubuntu with g++ via Virtual Box).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

void print(vector<int> v)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) cout << v[i] << " ";
  cout << endl;
}

vector<int> merge(vector<int> left, vector<int> right)
{
   vector<int> result;
   while ((int)left.size() > 0 || (int)right.size() > 0) {
      if ((int)left.size() > 0 && (int)right.size() > 0) {
         if ((int)left.front() <= (int)right.front()) {
            result.push_back((int)left.front());
            left.erase(left.begin());
         } 
   else {
            result.push_back((int)right.front());
            right.erase(right.begin());
         }
      }  else if ((int)left.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)left.size(); i++)
               result.push_back(left[i]);
            break;
      }  else if ((int)right.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)right.size(); i++)
               result.push_back(right[i]);
            break;
      }
   }
   return result;
}

vector<int> mergeSort(vector<int> m)
{
   if (m.size() <= 1)
      return m;

   vector<int> left, right, result;
   int middle = ((int)m.size()+ 1) / 2;

   for (int i = 0; i < middle; i++) {
      left.push_back(m[i]);
   }

   for (int i = middle; i < (int)m.size(); i++) {
      right.push_back(m[i]);
   }

   left = mergeSort(left);
   right = mergeSort(right);
   result = merge(left, right);

   return result;
}

int main()
{
   vector<int> v;

   v.push_back(38);
   v.push_back(27);
   v.push_back(43);
   v.push_back(3);
   v.push_back(9);
   v.push_back(82);
   v.push_back(10);

   print(v);
   cout << "------------------" << endl;

   v = mergeSort(v);

   print(v);
}
```

But when i insert the code to import the csv file, it only read the file and the sorting is not running, am i placed it wrong? Here is my code :

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

const int jumlahData = 999999;
double data[jumlahData] = {0};

void loadData(const char* namaFile) {
    string line;
    ifstream myfile (namaFile);

    if (myfile.is_open()) {
        int counter = 0;
        while (getline(myfile, line, ',')) {
            //cout << line << '\n';
            data[counter] = stod(line);
            counter++;
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
}

void print(vector<int> v)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) cout << v[i] << " ";
  cout << endl;
}

vector<int> merge(vector<int> left, vector<int> right)
{
   vector<int> result;
   while ((int)left.size() > 0 || (int)right.size() > 0) {
      if ((int)left.size() > 0 && (int)right.size() > 0) {
         if ((int)left.front() <= (int)right.front()) {
            result.push_back((int)left.front());
            left.erase(left.begin());
         } 
   else {
            result.push_back((int)right.front());
            right.erase(right.begin());
         }
      }  else if ((int)left.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)left.size(); i++)
               result.push_back(left[i]);
            break;
      }  else if ((int)right.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)right.size(); i++)
               result.push_back(right[i]);
            break;
      }
   }
   return result;
}

vector<int> mergeSort(vector<int> m)
{
   if (m.size() <= 1)
      return m;

   vector<int> left, right, result;
   int middle = ((int)m.size()+ 1) / 2;

   for (int i = 0; i < middle; i++) {
      left.push_back(m[i]);
   }

   for (int i = middle; i < (int)m.size(); i++) {
      right.push_back(m[i]);
   }

   left = mergeSort(left);
   right = mergeSort(right);
   result = merge(left, right);

   return result;
}

int main()
{
   vector<int> v;

   loadData("dataDemo.csv");

   print(v);
   cout << "------------------" << endl;

   v = mergeSort(v);

   print(v);
}
```

Comment: you can use `std::sort`.

Comment: and where your `loadData` write into `main::v`?

Comment: ... also, annotate your code so we can understand what your purpose of the directions it's taking is.

Comment: Your file data is stored in the global array `double data[]`, not a `vector<int>`.

Answer (score 1):

your `loadData("dataDemo.csv");` call does not writes to a previously declared local `vector<int> v;`. Your vector `v` has no elements. You need to write a method that populates vector `v` based on the contents of `double data[jumlahData]`
namely..

```
int main()
{
   vector<int> v;

   loadData("dataDemo.csv");
   populateVectorWithData(v, data); //TODO implement me
   print(v);
   cout << "------------------" << endl;

   v = mergeSort(v);

   print(v);
}
```

Comment: With you except for reading into the array and copying to the `vector` rather than reading directly into the `vector`. If, quoting the asker,  *[t]he file contains million of numbers* and the array size is less than a million, using the array just seems to be a really bad idea. Feeding the asker a bit of code demonstrating `loadData` with a `vector` and using `push_back` wouldn't rob them of too much education.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you tell me how to do it? i understand your answer a little bit, but i don't know what syntax to write and where it should be placed. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you are not sorting the actual data that you read in. This can be easily be solved by returning a count of the data-points you read-in.

A better approach, one that I suspect you are trying, is to send a reference of the vector from main to `loadData` and `push_back` the data on the vector. Furthermore, it is advisable to use your implementations provided libraries when possible. In other words, do not reinvent the wheel and just use `<algorithm>` instead of your own or someone else's sorting algorithm. It helps prevent nasty bugs.

```
int main()
{
  //return the count of integers read into data[] in loadData()
  //also change the vector & array types to be consistent, please!
  std::vector<int> v (data, loadData("dataDemo.csv");

  print(v);   //print the loaded vector
  cout << "------------------" << endl;

  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());  // using <algorithm> (̶i̶t̶'̶s̶ ̶q̶u̶i̶c̶k̶s̶o̶r̶t̶)̶

  print(v);
}
```

Comment: *it's quicksort* actuallyyyyy... it often isn't. These days it tends to be something called [introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort).

Comment: I'm sorry i forgot to tell, i only allowed to choose between merge/genetic sort, so can i use this method or no? thank you.

Comment: in `loadData` you use `counter++` to count how many numbers you've read-in. The `v` we construct in `main` needs to know that and also needs to know where `data` is hence why I do `std::vector<int> v (data, loadData("dataDemo.csv");`. Notice that I included the function call in the constructor, meaning that `v` completes construction after `loadData` *returns* with the `count` variable.